# .NET Core 2.0 achievement

Tags: java, asp.net, linux, .net-core

If there is any performanace comparison between java and .Net core.
Someone says java is better .
Can anyone have compared performance of .net core and java on linux server having same server configurations.

The most important question is that .net core brings the functionality i.e. running on linux in these last two years.
But why not developed eariler than this. On the other hand, java can run both linux and windows from so many years. 
 Is .Net is far behind from Java.

Comment: performance in case of speed, scalibility ,and response

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/08/22/net-core-benchmarking.aspx) article that measured .NET Core 2.0 Performance Against Java & Go.

Regarding .NET Core 2.0 vs Java, it writes:

> My overall impression is that .NET Core 2.0 and Java perform about the
>   same. Java possibly has a small edge on some calculations and array
>   manipulation and .NET having better parallel libraries.